# How to go back from the iOS 13 present viewController function animation and view to those of the previous iOS versions?

Tags: ios13, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, xcode11

After the release of iOS 13 and the update of XCode, the 'present(newViewController(), animated: true, completiton: nil)' function started displaying the new VC differently. The animation is still down to up, but now there is a margin between top of the screen and the beginning of the new VC, as well as the fact that now it is close-able by dragging downward.

I want the old way of presenting the new VC back: I want it to cover the entire screen (thus leaving no margin between top of screen and top of new VC), and no way to dismiss the new VC by dragging downward. How is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple, before presenting just add the following line

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```